# progressbar in Qlineedit

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am migrating some code from pyGObject to pyQT4 and I make use of set_progress_fraction as a means to indication the percentage of the MAXIMUM the inputted value is.

I am trying to find an equivalent in pyQT4 but I am failing. 
QLineEdit does have a paint method so is the only real way to "paint" the LineEdit?

--edit--
example of the gtk equiv:

[image]

& snippit of my present pyGObject code

```
 def on_entry_change(self,widget,*args):
      try:
          tmp = float(widget.get_text())
          tmp = (tmp- widget.min_bin)/(widget.max_bin - widget.min_bin)
          widget.set_progress_fraction(tmp)
      except:
          return
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to connect the value in the QLineEdit to a method that modifies the progress bar. This might help:

```
from __future__ import division
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import (Qt, SIGNAL)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QDialog, QLineEdit,
    QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QWidget, QLabel)

class Form(QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Form, self).__init__(parent)


    self.barA = QProgressBar()
    self.maximum = 200
    self.label1 = QLabel('Maximum = 200')
    self.seqM = QLineEdit("num")


    layoutO = QVBoxLayout() #set overal layout
    layoutO.addWidget(self.label1)
    layoutO.addWidget(self.barA)
    layoutO.addWidget(self.seqM)

    self.setLayout(layoutO)


    self.connect(self.seqM, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.updatebar) 
def updatebar(self):
    try:
        currval = float(self.seqM.text())
    except:
        print 'enter float or integer only'
    self.track = (currval/self.maximum)*100
    self.barA.setValue(self.track)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()`
```

Comment: thankyou for the reply. Not quite unfortunetly. I am more after a combine widget. This is an explanation of the gtk equiv: https://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/girdoc/C/Gtk.Entry.set_progress_fraction.html & a picture. http://www.system-tray-cleaner.com/systray/htm/wiki/images/4441ffcf221a1b65dad7f79c724f9b65.png